# Sculpting tools blender 2.82 don't work on iMac

Tags: sculpting

I am a complete newcomer to blender but opening a brand new version 2.82 file with factory default settings, selecting the cube in object mode and then going to sculpting mode the brushes appear can be modified but don't have any effect on the cube except distorting the corners.

---

I have just tried to open the default sculpting file from the splash screen and the sculpting tools work fine.  Don't understand why they don't work in the default mode.

Comment: Could you provide any screenshots or further detail on what you were trying to do? In it's current state this question is impossible to answer (it's not even a question, tbh).

Comment: Question has been answered Thank you.  Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sculpt tools operate on the existing vertices in the mesh, so in your case, they can only move around the 8 vertices that exist on the default cube.

Either subdivide the cube to add more vertices or enable Dyntopo which adds additional vertices as you sculpt to show the details.

[image]

Comment: Much obliged for your help.  All is clear now.

Comment: @MichaelRHarris If all is clear, please click on the check mark on the left hand side of this answer to indicate that your question has been resolved.